# Saving BLOBS in MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, blob, mysql-python

I am trying to save a file as a BLOB in a MySQL database.
The DB is very simple right now, a table with One column "File" as type longblob.

The code is as follows:

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
data = file.readlines()
dp = pickle.dumps(data,1)
sql = "insert into Files values (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(MySQLdb.escape_string(dp),))
```

This seems to upload fine, however when retrieving the data, I get an EOFError when trying to unpickle. If I try the process without pickling at all, the string is not unescaped and the escape characters stay in the string when written back to the file (unless there is a python step I am missing there to unescape/re-escape).

```
sql = "select File from Files"
cursor.execute(sql)
ret = cursor.fetchone()
pickle.loads(ret[0])

EOFError exception
```

Comment: why do you load `data` again  with `pickle.loads(data[0])` instead of the file you stored in your MySQL db and you request with cursor.fetchone() ? I expected to see something like `pickle.loads(ret.file)` didnt you ?

Comment: Have you considered using oursql instead?

Comment: Fixed the typo with 'data'.

At this time I have to use MySQL

Comment: Is that a "no, I haven't even bothered to look at what that is"?

Comment: With regards to `pickle.loads(ret.file)`, `cursor.fetchone()` returns a tuple, of which the first entry is a string.

Comment: Ignacio: If you are referring to oursql, its a "no, I don't manage the database environment". I can ask about installing the library, but I  presume MySQLdb or Mysql.connector can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the pickled list did not unpickle properly, but I was able to work around this by joining the readlines list into a string and upload it into MySQL as a longtext type.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use the MySQLdb.escape_string and the parameters style sql at same time.
these will work:

1,

```
sql = "insert into Files values (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(dp,))
```

2,

```
sql = "insert into Files values ('{}')".format(MySQLdb.escape_string(dp))
cursor.execute(sql)
```